# Does Forms Authentication in MVC work in a Mobile Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website in MVC that uses Forms Authentication. Would Forms Authentication work in a Mobile Browser ??

If not, how do I make the Authentication work in a Mobile Browser as well ??

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

Mobile browsers are functionally identical to desktop browsers - and have been since 2007 on the iPhone, and since 2010 on Android. Windows Phone's browser (2011-2017) was a better port of IE that can also be considered desktop-class that doesn't need any special-handling.

"Mobile browsers" were very different in their early years: 2000-2008, especially in low-end feature-phones where they might not even support cookies (hence "cookieless sessions"), but that's all obsolete now.

Windows Mobile's port of Internet Explorer from 2001 to 2010 did occupy a strange middle-ground but is irrelevant today - but in any event, it fully supported HTTP cookies so ASP.NET's `FormsAuthentication` system worked fine.

Note that in ASP.NET MVC today, `FormsAuthentication` itself is obsolete due to the redesign of authentication in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: So @Dai I don't need to change anything for Authentication ??

Comment: @SaiBand Correct. Have you tried it? Did you experience any issues?

Comment: I am developing the app on my local. Would only be able to try if I deploy to some public URL. So havent tried it yet ??

Comment: @SaiBand Mobile devices connected to your LAN via a wireless connection **can** connect to local websites by accessing `http://your-machine-name:port/website` - you don't need to put websites on a publicly accessible webserver.

Comment: @SaiBand That is beyond the scope of this posting.